# Postgis error "unknown spatial reference system" on ST_GeomFromGML

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to create a Postgis geometry from GML using ST_GeomFromGML. It results in an error message "unknown spatial reference system".

The GML has been created by Oracle function sdo_util.to_gml311geometry and looks like this:

```
<gml:Polygon srsName="SDO:28992" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
   <gml:exterior>
      <gml:LinearRing>
         <gml:posList srsDimension="2">...</gml:posList>
      </gml:LinearRing>
   </gml:exterior>
</gml:Polygon>
```

srsName SDO:28992 refers to the Oracle SRID 28992. What should I put in the GML so that PostGis understands this?

Comment: Does it have an equivalent in EPSG codes?

Comment: It should be EPSG:28992, Amersfoort / RD New. I have not see any WKIDs in Oracle's set that aren't the same as EPSG's, but Oracle does have their own definitions with their own range of values for the WKIDs.

Comment: I would try first by editing the GML to have "EPSG:28992" instead of "SDO:28992".